# ng-click wont trigger, function not working. Could it be scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, angularjs

I am trying to get an animation to work, when you click the search button it should be pulled to the right in order to allow the user to type whatever they want to search for. However, the ng-click doesn't even seem to trigger. I have tried "alert('its working');" several times but nothing pops up. The code is below, any ideas of what the problem could be?

**HTML:**

```
<li class="pull-right">
    <div>
    <!-- ngIf: showNavbarSearch --><div ng-if="showNavbarSearch" class="mat-slide-right pull-right ng-scope">
                                <form class="search-form form-inline ng-valid pull-left ng-pristine" ng-show="showNavbarSearch" ng-submit="submitNavbarSearch()">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="search-input">Search</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-input" placeholder="Search" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div><!-- end ngIf: showNavbarSearch -->

                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <button ng-click="toggleSearch()" class="btn btn-sm btn-link pull-left withoutripple">
                                    <i class="md md-search f20"></i>
                                </button>
    </div>
</li>
```

**JS:**

```
app.directive('navbarSearch', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: '/dist/assets/tpl/directives/navbar-search.html',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      $scope.showNavbarSearch = false;

      $scope.toggleSearch = function () {
        $scope.showNavbarSearch = !$scope.showNavbarSearch;
      };

      $scope.submitNavbarSearch = function(){
        $scope.showNavbarSearch = false;
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: your ng-click seems to be out of directive's scope.

Comment: I apologize, I am still learning as I go. What do you mean by out of directive's scope? Is it the placement of the code, or must I call the scope within the button?

Comment: is the `html` above the same as `/dist/assets/tpl/directives/navbar-search.html` ? does the submit works? can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes, the html above is the exact same as /dist/assets/tpl/directives/navbar-search.html minus the <li class="pull-right"></li>. I don't believe the submit works because absolutely nothing is happening. An animation should trigger but doesn't.

Comment: can you provide plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rc8qzwoa/  It is supposed to extend from the button to the search bar, but in visual studio the button does not activate anything.

Comment: you create a custom directive named "navbarSearch" but you don't use it in your template? I was expecting to see something like <div navbar-search> or <input navbar-search />

Comment: If all you need is ng-click, and ng-show/ng-hide, a controller itself should be enough, no need for a directive

Comment: I do use it, originally the code under `<div class="pull-right">` is supposed to be the only option. Then when I click the search button, it is supposed to call the `toggleSearch()` function. Which will then work the `<div ng-if="showNavbarSearch>`

Comment: Never mind, didn't read the question clearly, my bad

Comment: For some reason, it is not even getting to trigger `toggleSearch()`. I click the button and nothing happens.

Comment: check my posted code to see if it is what you'd want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help:

```
    app.directive('navbarSearch', [ function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'navbar-search.html',
        controller: function($scope){
          $scope.showNavbarSearch = false;
          $scope.mySearch = "";
          $scope.submitNavbarSearch = function(myVal){
            $scope.mySearch = myVal;
            console.log("submitting: " + $scope.mySearch);
            $scope.showNavbarSearch = false;
          }

          $scope.toggleSearch = function(){
            $scope.showNavbarSearch = !$scope.showNavbarSearch;
          }
        },

    };
}]);
```

Template:

```
<li class="pull-right">
<div ng-if="showNavbarSearch" class="mat-slide-right pull-right ng-scope">
  <form class="search-form form-inline ng-valid pull-left ng-pristine" ng-show="showNavbarSearch" ng-submit="submitNavbarSearch(mySearch)">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="search-input">Search</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="mySearch" placeholder="Search" autofocus="">
      </div>
  </form>
</div><!-- end ngIf: showNavbarSearch -->
<br />
<div class="pull-right">
  <button ng-click="toggleSearch()">
      <i class="md md-search f20">Toggle search</i>
  </button>
</div>
</li>
```

Usage:

```
<div navbar-search>

    </div>
```

Comment: Hmmmm, still nothing. Not quite sure what is going on. Rewriting the JS right now, I believe it has something to do with that

Comment: Fixed it, was missing a `navbar-search` in the `<div class="pull-right">` Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @aromans if the question is solved you need to mark the answer as correct